# merging two drawables in one recyclerview for different screen res

Tags: android, android-drawable

i'm trying to design this photo for my project

### [image: photo]

i successfully done it, but when i use other devices (different resolution) it look bad like this

### [image].

this is the adapter i use :

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private static final int RIGHT_BTN = 0;
    private static final int LEFT_BTN = 1;
    ArrayList<String> mList = new ArrayList<>();

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<String> mList) {

        this.mList = mList;
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if ((position % 2) == 0) {
            return RIGHT_BTN;
        }
        return LEFT_BTN;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {

        if (viewType == RIGHT_BTN) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.right_btn, viewGroup, false);
            return new ItemViewHolder(view);

        } else if (viewType == LEFT_BTN){
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.left_btn, viewGroup, false);
            return new HeaderViewHolder(view);

        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {


        if (holder instanceof HeaderViewHolder) {

        } else if (holder instanceof ItemViewHolder) {


        }


    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 114;
    }

    private class HeaderViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        View View;

        HeaderViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            View = itemView;
        }
    }

    private class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        View View;

        ItemViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            View = v;
        }
    }
}
```

and this is left_btn.xml

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

right_btn.xml

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/button2"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="73dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/right_circle_with_line"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

i use drawable to draw circles and line :

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:gravity="center">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_orange_light" />
            <size
                android:width="150dp"
                android:height="3dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:gravity="right">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_orange_light" />
            <size
                android:width="3dp"
                android:height="50dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:gravity="left">
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="oval">
            <stroke
                android:width="3dp"
                android:color="@android:color/holo_orange_light" />
            <solid android:color="#F2000000" />
            <size
                android:width="100dp"
                android:height="100dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

above codes are what i've tried but not working .
is there any ideas to solve this
like merging to different layouts in on layout with constrains?
or deferent idea for implementing this ?
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a different approach. Use a single layout and hide or show the left and right button based on position (using View.VISIBLE and View.INVISIBLE) and you can put the line down the center directly in the layout. Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageButton
    android:src="@drawable/left_button"
    android:id="@+id/left"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="4dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"/>

<ImageButton
    android:src="@drawable/right_button"
    android:id="@+id/right"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And then in code

```
if ( position % 2 == 0 ) { 
    findViewById( R.id.left ).setVisibile( View.VISIBLE ); 
    findViewById( R.id.right ).setVisibile( View.INVISIBLE ); 
} else { 
    findViewById( R.id.left ).setVisibile( View.INVISIBLE ); 
    findViewById( R.id.right ).setVisibile( View.VISIBLE ); 
}
```

Comment: not worked.
what i want is to merge left and right button in one row if current position is even it shows right button else shows left button like tree.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `android:layout_marginRight="40dp"` in right_btn.xml and left_btn.xml. `40dp` is not the same on different devices because devices can have different screen width in dp.

You need to calculate the offsed dynamically based on RecyclerView width to center your vertical line.

Comment: ok, i agree that this is one of the problems but how i can calculate the offset dynamically ?